# Regular expression for phone number validation

Tags: java, regex, validation

Hi I need regex for phone number validation for the below format

```
+1-646-222-3333
```

I have written expression like

```
^(+)([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})
```

But its not working. Can I know where I did wrong?

Comment: You could use Google's libphonenumber, it is dedicated to handling, well, phone numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
    String str = "+1-646-222-3333";
    if(str.matches("\\+\\d-\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}")) {
        System.out.println("Valid number");
    }else {
        System.out.println("Invalid number");
    }
```

Comment: simply superb thanx :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing the 1 in the beginning. And if you don't want to allow any trailing string, then you should mark the end of line `$.`

```
^(\+)([0-9]-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})$
       ^
```

EDIT: As noted, the `+` must be escaped.

Comment: Also, the `+` must be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

This works -

```
^(\+)([0-9]-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})
```

Test [here](http://regex101.com/r/aO9oA9)

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
^(\\+1)-([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})
       ^
      put this
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\+\d)*\s*(\(\d{3}\)\s*)*\d{3}(-{0,1}|\s{0,1})\d{2}(-{0,1}|\s{0,1})\d{2}$
```